# "spim: (parser) syntax error on line [...]" where i used the label .byte

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, att

When I'm programming in assembly and use the label `.byte`, I have a problem executing it with `Qtspim`. I tried to change the position or the value, but the problem persists and, probably, is the label.

The error reply was on line 3. At the end of the label you find the parser.

```
main:

.data
  v    : .byte 2,0,0,0,4,0,0,0
  array: .byte 2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,13,0,0,0,17,0,0,0,19,0,0,0

[..] # other code
```

When I change the directive `.byte` to `.space` the problem does not occur.

How could I resolve it?

Comment: It's not clear where the error occurs. Does it occur at the declaration site, or when you try to use the label later on? Also, why do you have the data section in the middle of the text section? They should completely separate.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a more extensive snippet of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that at least QtSpim requires the arrays to have space after the commas. So this will work just fine:

```
.data
v:  .byte 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0
```

Just remember to add a space after each value.

The reason for this is that the parser QtSpim uses allows the use of a comma or a dot as decimal separator. So it is confused about your definition unless there is a space to separate.

This would be allowed for defining a float:

```
flo:  .float 2,2
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sami. I didn't use the space between each value because at the lab doesn't exist difference. So i don't understand why the problem changes in difference computer ( my personal laptop and the PC lab).

Comment: @Andrew That's interesting. What I managed to get from the source code was that it should always require the space. But at least it should never complain if there is a space, so you can always just add it.